# InCopy tag creation request

Tags: discussion, support, status-declined, tags

My Super User question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1594517) involves Adobe InCopy. I would like to request the creation of a tag about Adobe InCopy. Could we please create such a tag? Thanks!

Comment: Why a version specific tag instead of InCooy tag?  Why are the application tags you used not enough?  You used multiple versions specific application tags for some reason

Comment: I've already removed the version-specific tags. I think if I add an InCopy tag, the probability that someone notices the question and leaves an answer will be greater. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is about Adobe Acrobat though?

Comment: If Adobe InDesign or InCopy is needed, I'll be willing to use them. So, it's mainly about Acrobat. P.S. I had both Adobe Acrobat Pro and Acrobat Pro DC tags since I thought that I wanted to have specific tags but I also wanted to draw attention using the more popular Adobe Acrobat Pro tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You question is only "if this program is needed", not actually about *using* Adobe Incopy.

The tag you want is not relevant in this case. We have a suggested edit reject reason that is relevant here:

> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is *about*, not just what it *contains*.

InCopy isn't the *topic* of your question, it is a distant tangent that *might* be vaguely relevant *if* it happens that someone thinks they might be able to do the task in it.

Being quite frank even the other adobe tags are not particularly relevant here, your only problem is with the PDF file itself, not the tools, otherwise we might as well have tags for every application that can edit or create PDFs.

So you would want tags for

- Foxit PhantomPDF
- PDFEscape
- SmallPDF
- Sedja PDF editor
- all the online editors
- all the PDF programming/editing frameworks?
- Hex editors, because you can technically view the content of a PDF in them?

In this case, no, the tag you want is not relevant.